# Handle continuous requests in spring mvc

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I am having a problem where there are multiple continuous requests hitting my spring controller in which I have to save the data received from each request into the database. Due to this I have to open the db connection every time and save the data, but what if these request's are in large numbers then how to handle this?
      Right now my tomcat get's hanged when the request's are in big numbers.

Comment: It sounds like your system does not scale as desired. Your problem description is not specific enough at the moment. Where is your bottleneck? Did you measure database response times? Do you reach a connection limit on the database or in your pool? Can you explain what "tomcat get's hanging" means? Are there any error messages? Please post more specific information (code, configuration) if you spotted a specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need a connection pool for your application so that db connection should not be open every time. You can find more reference here: https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-configure-the-c3p0-connection-pool-in-hibernate/ and https://javabeginnerstutorial.com/hibernate/connection-pooling-with-hibernate-4/

Comment: Thank you @Anuj Vishwakarma, but I already have c3po configured in my application. I exactly don't know why the server hanged when more number of request's came.

Comment: Can you check if you configured the pool setting i.e. no of threads and timeout for each connection. And maybe you are making too many requests on db more than the connection available and that will choke your application. See you application graph if you need a cache before database.

Comment: Yes I have <beans:property name="checkoutTimeout" value="30000" /> and   <beans:property name="maxIdleTime" value="30" /> set in my c3po config.

Comment: please post your whole config file if possible.

Comment: <beans:property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" /><beans:property name="jdbcUrl" value="${dbUrl}" /><beans:property name="user" value="${dbUsername}" /><beans:property name="password" value="${dbPassword}" /><beans:property name="minPoolSize" value="10" />  <beans:property name="maxPoolSize" value="15" /><beans:property name="acquireIncrement" value="5"/><beans:property name="checkoutTimeout" value="30000" /><beans:property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="30"/> <beans:property name="initialPoolSize" value="10" />
        <beans:property name="maxIdleTime" value="30" />